# How do I stop an instance of a custom DLL in Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows, vb.net, dll, windows-server-2008-r2

One of my Visual Studio projects generates a custom DLL that is run in a folder of the main web site (and the web site is a web site, not a web application, so I'm not publishing from VS - all files are copied manually).  Whenever I make changes and overwrite the DLL, I don't immediately see my changes, I suspect because the web site is running  the original DLL file cached in memory.

How can I identify and stop the process that is running the DLL?  Even if I delete the DLL from the folder the site still runs just fine, sans my changes.  I have also stopped and re-started the application pool and site in IIS.

"Back in the day" we would stop a svchost process, but I don't see anything like that in task manager.

Thanks for any help you may provide!
Mike

Comment: I should add that the DLL is implemented in an <object> tag in an aspx page, but even without the DLL in the location referred to in the <object> tag, the page loads just fine, as if it was there.

Answer (score 0):

Go and get [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), it has a feature called `DLL View` that will allow you to see which DLLs are being used by which process.

Read [Getting a list of DLLs currently loaded in a process](http://kb.froglogic.com/display/KB/Getting+a+list+of+DLLs+currently+loaded+in+a+process) for screenshots of how to enable `DLL View`.

Comment: Thanks, Karl Anderson, for the suggestion.  I downloaded the app and read the link, but was unable to find my DLL using the Process Explorer tool.